# APP Inventor get current user functionality

Tags: app-inventor

I know on the Google App engine there is support for Google Accounts via user = users.get_current_user() functionality.  I have used this and then I request the user to create account on my app.  Is there anyway for the phone app to gain assess to the the user = users.get_current_user() functionality?

I have seen the example of creating a register / login on AI and storing it on TinyDB but the Google UserID is already available on the app engine.  How do I access this functionality on the phone app?

Comment: Thank you. I guessed as much from my research.  How about this...I know I can use an Activity Starter to access my Google app engine login page.  If the user is successful, I could easily expose a userID as a string.  Can I return that string to the my App Inventor app? Is this possible and / or safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with OAuth you can ask the user for permission to view his email address and read that information from his Google profile, see an example how to do that with App Inventor here http://puravidaapps.com/taifunOA.php

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature does not exist.  It has been proposed and can be voted for [here](http://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=1390&can=1&q=email%20address&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Status%20Summary%20Reporter%20Stars).

Comment: To answer the question in your comment, how about using the new Web component to access your App Engine page, which could return the user id?